# Fixing an HP envy laptop after bios update issue

Tags: windows-10, bios, hardware-failure, hp-envy

I have an HP ENVY laptop, up until last week it was working OK, and then when I switched it on, there was a message that I had to do bios update , the update started automatically after a few minutes my computer went blank I waited for like an hour, nothing happened, I switched it off and tried switching on, nothing happened I tried all combinations of advice from HP CTRL+B, V (with a BIOS software on a USB) nothing. They suggest that in case everything fail, it is a hardware issue without saying which hardware to check.
Does anyone know anything I can do ?
I have opened it removed the battery and reconnected again, same thing.

any help appreciated

Comment: Sounds like the firmware update bricked your system.  You will have to contact HP for assistance

Comment: how to contact them, via website etc... I need assistance please

Comment: The contact information for HP is on their website.